# How to navigate to certain page from reviewing pane?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, comments, navigation

A few weeks ago, I could navigate to certain page contain the comment using reviewing pane by clicking on the comment on reviewing pane. Suddenly I can't do it again now. When I click the comment on reviewing pane, it only showing the page on the reviewing pane itself. This become irritating because I must scrolling the page manually to find the page that contain the comment. This make the reviewing pane is not useful anymore.

[This is the comment from reviewing pane before it was clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0WFP.png)

[This what happen when I clicked the comment:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXKE5.png)

**UPDATE:**
I'm using Office 2013

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. I'm running the desktop version of Microsoft 365 Version 2011 (Build 13426.20308), what version are you running? You could also try shutting down and restarting your computer.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office 2013. This happen everytime, restart the computer does not help.

Comment: Then we know Microsoft hasn't pushed any updates to your version of Word. Something else has happened. Try a restart of your computer and test if this Is only happening in this one document.

Comment: I have tried to another document, it also doesn't work on the other document. I have restart my PC, still not working.

Comment: Are you in Outline View? You have to be in Print Layout, Draft or Web View in order for  Review Pane navigation to work.

Comment: I'm on the print view

Comment: Try starting Word in safe mode. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-Office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-Windows-PC-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72